# Insufficient permissions in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I resolve the vs code Insufficient permission issue when saving a file

I've given appropriate permissions to code directory:
chown -R me:staff my-app/

But when I open vscode and try to save a file it says "Insufficient permissions, Retry as admin"

If I launch vscode with sudo from cmd line sudo code . then I dont get that error but then the autocompletion extensions dont seem to work

Comment: Where is your project located? It may be folder's permissions

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto project location is `~/Code/my-app`

Comment: How did you install vscode?

Comment: It should be `chmod` instead of `chown` like **chmod -R 766 my-app**.

Comment: You or the logged in User account seem to not have permission to read and write to the folder where the file is located. I have posted you my answer below, add your account to the folder and grant read and write permission.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add your User or the User who is currently logged in to the folder and grant Read and Write access.

[image]

Comment: Why would anyone post a screen shot that is not in English like that???

Comment: steps are pretty common, the key detail here is the dropdown of the permission. Do you expect everyone will switch language settings just for a screenshot?

Answer (score 165):

Try this code:

```
sudo chown -R username directory_name
```

where,

- `username` is the username of the user of the laptop you want to give access for
- `directory_name` is the name of the directory whose permissions you want to change

Comment: This answer is a better way than the accepted answer that applies all permission to the files and directories.

Comment: worked on Ubuntu didnt get any more problems

Comment: The best solution! Solved it for me, thanks.

Comment: worked on PopOS. This problem was driving me crazy

Comment: I had copied my `.config/Code/` directory to another PC, got the same issue as the OP, and this fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: By the way, if you need to find your directory_name, see this article (don't download the clean my mac just ignore) https://macpaw.com/how-to/get-file-path-mac

Comment: `username` can be replaced by `$(whoami)` in case you are granting to the logged in user. so, `sudo chown -R $(whoami) directory_name`

Answer (score 113):

Change the permission level of your project directory, for example:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 testproject
```

Comment: this is a bad way, i think he should change permission of the folder or the vs code

Comment: This worked for me but not sure if its the safest way.

Comment: ichimaru, why is it bad?

Comment: You should not grant *everyone* write permission. This is easily abused by bad guys who manage to break into a low-privilege account to gain additional privileges.

Comment: I think this way is RISKY

Comment: How to update the permission of VS Code? @ichimaru

Comment: This approach is not the safest, but I wanted to mention that it worked for me when I faced the problem from zsh in WSL

Comment: I'm not very versed in Linux stuff, but as far as I know you should never suggest 777 permissions as it opens concerning security risks. I thknk a better solution is to keep it the way Mohit Sinha described, even though it seems OP tried that. VSCode still asks them to use an Administrator user, so maybe their only problem is that their current account isn't Admin

Comment: [Mohit Sinha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62515421/3702377) is a better way without applying all permission to the files and directories.

Comment: if you are project folder, example: testproject - go one step previous folder using cd.. (cd double dot)

Answer (score 25):

Try with the below command(For linux/mac)

**sudo chown -R abhinav-kumar my-app**

Let’s break this down.

- sudo – admin rights must be used since we are dealing with a folder that belongs to another user
- chown – the command for changing ownership
- -R – the recursive switch to make sure all child objects get the same ownership changes
- abhinav-kumar – the new owner of the folder
- my-app – the directory to be modified

Comment: Good answer. The breakdown is helpful and is often missing from many answers.

Comment: thank you very much, I also really liked that you broke the answer down so people would actually understand it. Nice work man!

Answer (score 16):

***Should I give you a fish? Nope.. that's is not right at all!
I should teach you how to fish and it'll save you for a lifetime.***

Dear anyone, the issue is all about access permission to that directory or even file sometimes. So you need to use `chmod` command to change access permission and we normally use access codes which work as a combination of three octal digits (0-7).

> The three `chmod` codes set permissions for these three groups in this
> order:
>
> ```
>  1. Owner (you)
>  2. Group (a group of other users that you set up)
>  3. World (anyone else browsing around on the file system)
> ```
>
> Each digit of this code sets permissions for one of these groups as
> follows. Read is 4. Write is 2. Execute is 1.
>
> The sums of these numbers give combinations of these permissions:
>
> ```
> 0 = no permissions whatsoever; this person cannot read, write, or execute the file
> 1 = execute only
> 2 = write only
> 3 = write and execute (1+2)
> 4 = read only
> 5 = read and execute (4+1)
> 6 = read and write (4+2)
> 7 = read and write and execute (4+2+1)
> ```

Read more from this [article](https://www.december.com/unix/ref/chmod.html)

Hence, in your case you could try running `sudo chmod 777 folder-name` which I'm sure it's gonna work! **But...** *It's not safe for use!!! keep it away from the reach of yourself! IT'S A RISK!*..

I would suggest to try 755 to make it work. Or something different since you now understand what you're doing! *(I mean to fish!)*

Answer (score 9):

Please, don't use `777` for permissions, it's a security risk.

### You must be the owner of all files and folders

In your project folder run (replacing `<user>` with your username):

```
chown <user>:<user> -R .
```

If any file is owned by `root`, then it'll require `sudo`.

### All folders must have permission `755`

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

### All source code files must  have permission `644`

Let's start changing only the source files. As my project is a **Python** project, let's apply the change initially only for `.py` source files (change the extension to your source files):

```
find -name "*.py" -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

### Done

Check if it works.

**If this is not enough**, you can **additionally** change permission of all project files to `644`, but maybe this will change the permission for images and some executables.

So, **being warned that you can change images and binaries permissions**:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

Answer (score 7):

The two simplified steps i found useful are:

1. cd to that directory`cd /var/www/target-directory`
2. change ownership to home user where vscode has all write-read permissions`chown $(whoami) -R .`
3. Then do `code .` to open current directory in vscode and everything should be working.

> `$(whoami)` - pipes the result of the current user for home to `chown` command. Its concise and direct.
> -R command instructs `chown` to recursively change sub directories in this directory

Answer (score 5):

sudo chmod -R a+rwx folder_of_work

This will work.
Will make available all permissions: write, read and execute from all to the folder of work.
The -R is for making all these permissions also on the files and folders inside the folder_of_work.

Answer (score 3):

You can just change the ownership of your project folder.

```
sudo chown -c -R $USER:$USER (project folder)
```

Explanation:

- chown: change the ownership of files/directories
- c: report all changes
- -R: do this recursively (for all files/directories beneath the given one)
- $USER:$USER: change the owner and the group that owns the entry to the user that issues the command (sudo preserves the values)
- (project folder): name of the folder which contains project files

You can test those environment variables with the following commands

```
echo $USER
sudo echo $USER
```

Answer (score 3):

Give permission to your project folder like below

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER your_project_folder_name
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error after executing sudo git pull on ubuntu, The issue was solved by Changing the file/directory persons for the owner, group and others for all the files and the folders for the project by running
**sudo chmod -R 770 projectFolder** don't run **sudo chmod -R 777 projectFolder** for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

On Windows10, I solved adding "modify" permissions (to "authenticated users") to the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**
Problem to save App.js file in React App.

**VSCODE Error : Failed to save 'App.js': insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser.**

**Solution For Linux**

```
sudo chown -R UserName AppName
```

**Example**

```
sudo chown -R yogi my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had same problem am working on windows 10 OS

just from Project folder -> Properites -> UnCheck Read-Only in attributes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you somehow changed file ownerships in your home directory.

One way to correct this without endangering your system is

```
sudo chown -c -R $USER:$USER $HOME
```

Explanation:

chown:  change the ownership of files/directories
-c: report all changes
-R: do this recursively (for all files/directories beneath the given one)
$USER:$USER: change the owner and the group that owns the the entry to the user that issues the       command (sudo preserves the values)
$HOME: do this with your home directory

You can test those environment variables with the following commands

```
echo $USER
sudo echo $USER
echo $HOME
sudo echo $HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by changing the permissions of the project user to yourself.

However, if you change the permissions of a file, when you are developing a team, you can end up pushing even the permissions of the file to git.

If this happens, you may be warned by the team.

So, it would be better if you change the permissions of your local project folder and at the same time ignore the push of file permission changes to git.

This way, files with changed permissions won't be published online.

```
$ sudo chown -R userName /Users/userName/projectName
$ cd /Users/userName/projectName
$ git config core.filemode false
$ git config -l | grep filemode
```

Verify that `core.filemode = false`

#### about

git config core.filemode is set to true by default, and if it's not set to false, it will automatically convert to 644 if the permissions are set to 755

[【Vscode】How to solve the problem when a file cannot be updated due to lack of permissions in vscode](https://off.tokyo/blog/permissions-vscode/)

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10 my Antivirus was the reason for this error to happen.

I had to add the folder where the file I wanted to save was to the excluded folder of my Ransomware protection.

Answer (score 0):

> Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as
> superuser.

In Ubuntu 20.04 try these commands to give the right permission to your files and folders:

```
cd /PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data .
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Then try to save your files again.

Answer (score 0):

Add the user logging in via the RemoteSSH to the group that owns the files/folders and set the folder permissions to g+w.

Remember to restart/reboot the RemoteSSH server/machine to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is to simply switch to bash in terminal. This will allow you to modify files as usual. When you start your project, use sudo.

For example: sudo nom start

Answer (score 0):

simply try exiting vscode (by discarding changes if 'save as sudo' doesn't work either) and **relaunch vscode**

Answer (score -3):

This is because you are not running VS Code as administrator. So VS Code does not have permission to save files.

You should always run VS Code as administrator. To do this, go to the folder where you installed it. By default, VS Code is installed under `C:\users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code` .

Find the file "Code.exe" and open properties, go to the tab "Compatibility" and check the field "Run this program as administrator".

This method worked out well for me.

Comment: This is terrible advice.

Comment: As a general rule, you should avoid running applications as admin unless absolutely necessary. Here you should modify permissions of the code directory so that you don't need admin to save there.

Comment: so what's the solution for windows please?

Answer (score -4):

Try open the vs code with run as administrator

Comment: `sudo` is a macOS command, nothing to do with windos `run as admin`.