# VSCode Remote SSH file permissions for group

Tags: vscode-remote

I see the answers [Insufficient permissions in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674627/insufficient-permissions-in-vscode), but they all mean changing the owner of the file which I do not want to do.

Situation:

- User X & Y
- User X currently owns the file/folder with group X
- I have added user Y to group X
- I have changed permissions such that group X has RWX permissions
- On a terminal (PuTTY) SSH session, logged in as Y - I can edit/save files owned by user/group X

When logged in with VSCode Remote SSH, I can read, but do not have permission to write the file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to reboot the remote device so it restarted the VSCode Server.

If you need more than one user to be able to access a set of files, add the user 'logging in' to the group and set the group permissions to RW for the file structure.